# What does un-shimmable mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I read through the [vuejs2 documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked) and found this part:

> This is an ES5-only and un-shimmable feature, which is why Vue doesn’t support IE8 and below.

I think it means that the feature is not possible to be monkey patched, but I'm not sure.

So what is a (un-)shimmable feature in JavaScript exactly all about?

Comment: Yes, that's a fair summary: making the feature work requires more than an added/updated "monkey patched" method. An un-shimmable feature is one that requires a core "engine" change due to some intrinsic property or operation that did not occur in a previous EMCAScript version. For example, ES6 generators are "un-shimmable". (There are ES6 to ES5 transpilers; shims generally must work with 'the source as it is'.)

Comment: That's a great answer. Go for it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You got it right, a shim is a patch that provides otherwise unavailable functionality or a language feature.

Some features, however, require support from the underlying JS engine, and cannot be created purely in Javascript. I imagine that's what they meant.